# Get select option by value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have selection menu:

```
<div class="selector">
<select>
<option value="valueA">Value A</option>
<option value="valueB">Value B</option>
<option value="valueC">Value C</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and I need Javascript (no jquery!) to get option by value and change it's text (innerHtml)

for example when I run the function I need to get option with the value "valueB" from class "selector" and change it's text to Value Whatever.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
document.querySelector('div.selector option[value=valueB]').text = 'Value whatever';
```

Further, in answer to the questions raised in comments:

> I need to get only the second `<option>` element with the same value as the other `<option>` and change text only to the second `<option>`

To get all `<option>` elements with `value="valueB"`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.selector option[value=valueB]')[1].text = 'Value whatever';
```

The differences are that `document.querySelector()` returns only the first (if *any*) match to the supplied CSS selector, as a node (rather than a `NodeList`), so properties are available directly; `document.querySelectorAll()` returns *all* the elements, in a `NodeList`, that match the supplied selector; so we have to use the (zero-based) index (`[1]`) to retrieve a specific node, and get/set its properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('[value=valueB]').innerHtml="innerHtml"
```

for text `document.querySelector('[value=valueB]').text="text"`